# Are there frameworks for Jython or JRuby, or is it you can run a py or ruby app on the JVM?

Tags: java, python, jvm, jruby, jython

Are there specific frameworks for Jython or JRuby, or is it you can run a py or ruby app on the JVM?

i.e. you take your python django app, and you can run in on tomcat using jython?

Sorry little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JRuby 1.5.X is compatible with Ruby 1.8.7, and pretty much anything you write in Ruby will work in JRuby. This includes applications written in frameworks such as Ruby on Rails, which can be converted to a war file and deployed to Tomcat. In fact the [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/) comes with Ruby on Rails support and by default you're using JRuby. This makes it easy if you're just getting started with the language and/or the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right. You can run django framework python in jython, which will run on the JVM, so I think you're in good shape.
http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/09/state-of-python-on-the-jvm has a lot more details that may help you with specific ways to do this.